# postfix: blocking a certain sender for a certain receiver

Tags: postfix, amavis, postfwd

I have a postfix installation with amavis and postfwd.
I'd like to block a single sender only for a single receiver.
I tried with header_checks but multiline checking 
I was thinking something like

```
id=BLOCKIT
sender==badsender@domain.com; recipient==myreceiver@domain.com; action=REJECT no sender
```

on postfwd but I can't find the proper syntax...
Has anyone some suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do this in `postfwd`, but within Postfix, you can use [Restriction Classes](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html) for this. If you e.g. want to prevent `bob@example.net` to send mail to your user `alice@example.com`:

```
smtpd_restriction_Classes = mail_for_alice
mail_for_alice = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/mail_for_alice
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  ...
  check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/special_recipients
```

The file `special_recipients` would contain a line like

```
alice@example.com mail_for_alice
```

And `mail_for_alice` would contain:

> bob@example.net reject

That said, you are *probably* better of with doing all of this in `postfwd` ;-)

Comment: tried this but it was not working in my case: I needed to skip bounces only for a certain user... I  would have liked to drop MAILER-DAEMON messages only to him, looks like restrictions are before bounces and probably even postfwd would not have worked... I finished using another workaround with an alias to a script

Answer (score 2):

I have accomplished similar tasks using [Postgrey](http://postgrey.schweikert.ch/). You could install postgrey and disable the greylisting feature, but retain the whitelist and blacklist features. Many people find Postgrey intrusive, I find it to be a nearly perfect spam filter.

Comment: thanks the best option would be using or postfwd or amavisd that are already installed and working, I'd rather not add extra software again